# Quarto output executable RMD/QMD file with text includes

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm using quarto (v1.4) to put together an assignments for my a course, giving them the option to use either Python (.ipynb) or R (.rmd) to complete it.  I'm giving them a template to get started, and having them edit some existing code.

I have some generic preamble & question text that I want to be uniform between the R and Python versions of the document, as well as some generic imports for Python (e.g., matplotlib) and R (e.g., ggplot2) that I want to import for each assignment.  So my strategy is to have two documents (Assignment1_py.qmd & Assignment1_R.qmd), where the code blocks are different, but the preamble, question text, etc. are brought in using includes.  An example for the python version is at the bottom.  The `keep-ipynb: true` command allows me to output the a nicely formatted .ipynb file, which the students can then work with.

My question is: is there a way to do something similar with R?  There isn't an equivalent `keep-rmd: true` option. If they download the raw .QMD file, then the code works, but the include files are not rendered.  The best option I've found so far is to set `keep-md: true`, to keep the intermediary .md file.  It works, but the code blocks are not formatted properly (shown below) so I need a second second script to reformat the code cells and save as a .rmd file that the students can work with.  Its not a huge problem, but I'm curious if there is a more elegant solution?

#### Python

````
---
title: "Assignment 1 Py"
jupyter: python3
execute:
  keep-ipynb: true
---


{{< include _Includes/01_Preamble.qmd >}}

{{< include _Includes/ImportPy.qmd >}}

{{< include _Includes/01_Q1.qmd >}}
```{python}
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GEOS300/AssignmentData/main/Climate_Summary_BB.csv",
            parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'],
            index_col=['TIMESTAMP']
            )

Start ='2023-06-21 0000'
End ='2023-06-21 2359'

Selection = df.loc[(
    (df.index>=dt.datetime.strptime(Start, '%Y-%m-%d %H%M'))
    &
    (df.index<=dt.datetime.strptime(End, '%Y-%m-%d %H%M'))
    )]

Selection.head()

```

{{< include _Includes/01_Q2.qmd >}}
````

#### R

````
---
title: "Assignment 1 R"
execute:
  keep-md: true
---

{{< include _Includes/01_Preamble.qmd >}}


{{< include _Includes/01_Q1.qmd >}}

```{r}
#|echo: True

library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")


df <- read.csv(file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GEOS300/AssignmentData/main/Climate_Summary_BB.csv')
df[['TIMESTAMP']] <- as.POSIXct(df[['TIMESTAMP']],format = "%Y-%m-%d %H%M")

head(df)

```


{{< include _Includes/01_Q2.qmd >}}
````

#### MD Output for R

````
::: {.cell}

```{.r .cell-code}
#|echo: True

list.of.packages <- c("ggplot2", "reshape2")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
```
:::
````

Comment: I think this may be an interesting question but can you post what your expected output would be and what you expect students to do with it? I don't see why you couldn't just use the original `qmd` file, rather than generating an `rmd`. Is it because of the `{{include}}` blocks - you want to distribute one file? Also right now this is not reproducible. Can you just have one minimal include block which you include in the question? Finally, Quarto is still relatively new and there are significant differences between versions 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4, so it's worth adding which version you're using.

Comment: The reason for not using the qmd filed directly is that it adds another layer of complexity (students needing to install and understand quarto).  I added the vesion (v1.4).  Can try to add a reproducible example a bit later today.

Comment: Is it really another layer? I'd expect most of your students using R to be doing so in RStudio which [ships with Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/tools/rstudio.html). I use VS Code which also has a [Quarto extension](https://quarto.org/docs/tools/vscode.html) - admittedly you need to install it and Quarto but I imagine anyone choosing to use VS Code for R is savvy enough to work out how to do so. The same applies to other IDEs. In any case, you seem to be creating separate files for R and Python. If you're committed to rmd, could you just write the R version as an rmd rather than qmd?

Comment: Ships with Quarto? It supports the format, but I believe you still have to install Quarto as a separate program first, which is what Skeeter is worried about.   
But with Rmarkdown, you also have to install the rmarkdown package, right? Although package installation is less work than a full program install.

Comment: @mkranj recent versions of RStudio seen to include it - [RStudio users will have Quarto available by default for the RStudio UI, at the R console, and in the integrated terminal](https://docs.posit.co/resources/install-quarto/#use-bundled-quarto)

Comment: Thanks - I see it does come with Quarto now.  I'm not a big R user so I hadn't updated to the version that ships with R.

Comment: @JuneSkeeter I would be slightly careful though as the version of Quarto people that your students will be using will depend on when they installed RStudio and there really are quite significant differences between versions, including the versions of other libraries they include (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928247/how-to-bold-text-using-markdown-in-mermaid-diagram-in-quarto/77928635#77928635) Quarto mermaid.js question from yesterday).