# How to bold text using markdown in mermaid diagram in Quarto

Tags: r, markdown, quarto, mermaid

I can't figure out why the below code isn't working to render **bold** text. I have a mermaid diagram for a Quarto website in R, and I want the word **parameterChoiceUI** to be in bold. This is what I have  in my .qmd file:

````
```{mermaid}
%%{init: {"flowchart": {"htmlLabels": false}} }%%
flowchart LR
  A["`**parameterChoiceUI**
    Indicator Selection`"]
  A --> C(Modules)
  B[sliderUI] --> C(Modules)
  C --> D{Plots}
```
````

However, the rendered diagram looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown support to format text in mermaid diagram was added in [mermaid.js `v10.1.0`](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/releases/tag/v10.1.0) and Quarto [v1.4 uses mermaid `v10.2.0`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/news/changelog-1.4.md#mermaid-diagrams), whereas Quarto [v1.3 uses mermaid `v9.2.2`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/news/changelog-1.3.md#mermaid-diagrams).

So I think, you are using a quarto version below 1.4. Upgrade to Quarto v1.4 and your provided example should work fine (working fine in my case with Quarto v1.4).

[image: markdown support in mermaid diagram]

Comment: Ahhhh THANK YOU SO MUCH! That was exactly the problem. Appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 2):

It should work with HTML, e.g.

```
A["`<b>parameterChoiceUI</b>
    Indicator Selection`"]
```

Comment: Many thanks. Didn't see any references to HTML support anywhere else, so I would have forgotten to test this if not for your answer.